# Android Bitmap OnDraw

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a layout in my myviewlay.xml but this is not working, what am i missing?

```
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

       imageBack =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.layout.myviewlay, null);
    }
```

Comment: I am new to android, I am just trying to place the layout i created ... right now it just shows a black screen.. – user710502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to do the actual drawing:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(imageBack, x, y, mPaint); //replace x,y,and mPaint with whatever you need to.
```

However, if you're trying to display an entire layout use `setContentView(imageBack)` or something similar. It's recommended to do your layout in XML.

Update: Sorry I misunderstood you at first. It looks like you ARE trying to inflate a layout from XML. In that case, in your onCreate(), call `setContentView(R.layout.myviewlay);`

Comment: Wow thank you i was able to do it with the drawBitmap..., can i add image views from the OnDraw and if so how ?

Comment: Please see my update. It is MUCH better to do it with setContentView() like I mentioned. Put all your layout building into onCreate not onDraw. To add an ImageView, create a new ImageView then use (a reference to your parent view).addView(your ImageView). You Can use onDraw to add images such as bitmaps and simple geometry. Check out this resource for onDraw help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html And be sure to look through the rest of the site as well! Good luck learning Android.